# Find deepest level in different jsons

Tags: jolt

I have different type of JSONs. I'll provide three of them to explain logic:

```json
{
  "error" : {
    "code" : "validation_failed",
    "message" : "Validation failed",
    "fields" : {
      "banners" : {
        "code" : "bad_items",
        "message" : "Bad items in list",
        "items" : [ {
          "code" : "active_banners_limit",
          "message" : "Limit of active banners exceeded"
        } ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```json
{
  "error" : {
    "code" : "validation_failed",
    "message" : "Validation failed",
    "fields" : {
      "date_end" : {
        "code" : "min_value",
        "message" : "Value is less than minimum allowed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "validation_failed",
        "message": "Validation failed",
        "fields": {
            "targetings": {
                "fields": {
                    "geo": {
                        "fields": {
                            "regions": {
                                "unallowed_values": [
                                    100000000
                                ],
                                "code": "unallowed_value",
                                "message": "Unallowed value"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I should go to `error.fields...` and find the deepest level and grab `code` and `message` from it and concat them with `|`. I don't know exactly how many levels can be, and my goal message always inside deepest one. So I expect:

[
{
"errorMessage": "active_banners_limit|Limit of active banners exceeded"
}
]

[
{
"errorMessage": "min_value|Value is less than minimum allowed"
}
]

[
{
"errorMessage": "unallowed_value|Unallowed value"
}
]

Is it possible? It's not a problem to get `code` and `message` when u know structure and needed json level, but here we don't know.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Generally on Stack Overflow it's expected and required for you to attempt something before asking a question, and to include your attempt in your question.

Comment: I don't think it could be possible for the current version of Jolt.